# How to play mpg file in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, video

How to play "wmv" or "mpg" file in asp.net page.
For that what should i do.

Need help.

Comment: The information you have given is not enough to answer you for us, please provide some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Open the HTML page in which you want the player embedded and place the following tag within the  tag where you want it to be displayed:

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="true" EnableContextMenu="false" autostart="false" width="320" height="240" loop="false" src="MyVideo.wmv" />
```

Be sure to have a video file named MyVideo.wmv in the same directory with the HTML file, or simply change the src attribute to point to the path of a real video file.